# Best way of sending request to child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating a map application that consists of a map (react-map-gl) showing GeoJSON markers and a simple table that lists the properties of the same markers.

Both the map component and the table component are direct children of a common component (the main App component). When clicking a marker in the table, I want the map component to zoom to this marker.

For the map to start a transition, I need to set its state.viewport like shown in this example:
https://visgl.github.io/react-map-gl/docs/advanced/viewport-transition

If you move the "New York City" button in that example to a sister component instead, you have my case exactly.

How do I send a map transition request from a sister component to the map component in the "React way"?

Comment: You should make the parent component transmit the change from his state to the children props. Your component with the button should trigger a onTransition handler transmitted by the parent as prop. The role of the handler is to alter the state of the parent based on your logic. Do you need an example ?

Comment: Thanks, @jbg. I don't think I need an example, but perhaps a slightly more detailed explanation would help a lot! Transmitting from the button component to the parent using a handler is fine, it's sending it on down to the map that's my issue. So perhaps you could elaborate on the "make the parent component transmit the change from his state to the children props" a bit? How can I transmit this change using props without the map component initiating the transition on every render (as the props are static)?

Comment: You can use contexts to communicate or share data between components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The React way is to have a common parent that will handle all state related actions, that is called [lifting your state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html). The idea is to always keep a single source of truth, let it go down the tree via props and use function to update the state.

In your case, a single exemple could look like this:

```
const defaultViewport = viewport: {
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    longitude: -122.45,
    latitude: 37.78,
    zoom: 14,
}

// The app will handle the viewport and related update
const App = () => {
    const [viewport, setViewport]= useState(defaultViewport);

    const handleTransition = (transitionViewport) => {
        setViewport({
            ...viewport,
            ...transitionViewport
        });
    }

    const handleViewportChange = (newViewport) => {
        setViewport(newViewport);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <Map 
                viewport={viewport}
                onViewportChange={handleViewportChange}
            />

            <Menu 
                onTransition={handleTransition}
            />
        </div>
    );
}

// The map only need to be aware of the viewport and how to change it
const Map = ({ viewport, onViewportChange }) => {
    return (
        <ReactMapGL 
            {...viewport} 
            onViewportChange={onViewportChange} 
        />
    );
}


// The menu only need to know how to request a transition
const Menu = ({onTransition}) => {
    const goToNYC = () => {
        const viewport = {
            longitude: -74.1,
            latitude: 40.7,
            zoom: 14,
            transitionDuration: 5000,
            transitionInterpolator: new FlyToInterpolator(),
            transitionEasing: d3.easeCubic
        };

        onTransition(viewport);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={goToNYC}>New York City</button>
        <div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Ah, of course. I considered the viewport so tightly coupled to the map that I didn't even consider lifting that up. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a parent component that will handle the state changes and then send the state and handler as props to the child components.

For example below, you have a parent component called `MyApp` which has two child components, `Map` which contains the map and `NYCButton` which contains the button that triggers the state change.

The `MyApp` component...

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { FlyToInterpolator } from "react-map-gl";
import d3 from "d3-ease";
import { Map } from "./Map";
import { NYCButton } from "./NYCButton";

const MyApp = () => {
  const [viewport, setViewport] = useState({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    longitude: -122.45,
    latitude: 37.78,
    zoom: 14
  });

  const goToNYC = () => {
    setViewport({
      ...viewport,
      longitude: -74.1,
      latitude: 40.7,
      zoom: 14,
      transitionDuration: 5000,
      transitionInterpolator: new FlyToInterpolator(),
      transitionEasing: d3.easeCubic
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="MyApp">
      <Map viewport={viewport} onViewportChange={setViewport} />
      <NYCButton goToNYC={goToNYC} />
    </div>
  );
};

export { MyApp };
```

The `Map` component...

```
mport React from "react";
import ReactMapGL from "react-map-gl";

const Map = ({ viewport, onViewportChange }) => (
  <div>
    <ReactMapGL {...viewport} onViewportChange={onViewportChange} />
  </div>
);

export { Map };
```

The `NYCButton` component...

```
import React from "react";

const NYCButton = ({ goToNYC }) => (
  <div>
    <button onClick={goToNYC}>New York City</button>
  </div>
);

export { NYCButton };
```

Comment: Thanks to you as well! Sorry, I can only mark one answer as correct, and as they were so similar, I marked the first one.

Comment: No problems! :-)